# How to run adhoc SQL queries on flat files generated by Hive?

Tags: javascript, sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

We analyze of our log data using Hive and we store the aggregation results in daily partitioned text fields on S3 (let's call them "coarse" aggregations).

These aggregation results are rather small (not more than a few MB per day) and we have a Javascript dashboard that loads and visualizes certain aspects of this data (let's call them "fine-grained" aggregations).

Right now we perform the "fine-grained" aggregations with Javascript code. I rather want to use SQL queries here, too, for simplicity. I wonder what best practices exists for this kind of problem?

**A)** We could generate all "fine-grained" aggregations in Hive. However, operating on these small data sets takes ages in Hive.

**B)** We could introduce a "fast-access-layer" between S3 and Javascript that can run SQL queries. What query engine would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Presto**](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/) for fast access to not very big datasets. 
Presto is an in-memory distributed SQL query engine and optimized for interactive queries, star schema joins(big fact table with small dimensions). Memory to memory data transfer without disk writes is a key feature of presto. You can query your Hive tables using [**Presto Hive connector**](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html).

Comment: Agreed, Presto is a great choice for fast interactive SQL under concurrency. In addition, ability to put data in multiple storage engines may broaden the use cases: https://www.slideshare.net/kbajda/presto-talk-at-odsc-boston-2018